# PHP best practice to handle IP block and flood control for user login

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

My every coding & algorithm set up are  ok, but required your advice, that if I'm going into the direction or not. I have two concerns where  advice/review is required.

**Concern I: Algorithm**

In the login page, we don't use google recaptcha. But we have following logic to control flood & block ip:

- For each non user failed login attempt, we store his IP on mysql "flood" table with IP & time.
- This way we store & check maximum 20 attempts in last 2 hours. If it occurs, then we delete all flood records related to that IP & add that IP into "block_ip" mysql table.

For each of our PHP pages(30+) we call following IP block function to redirected blocked IP visitors into the "block.php" page.

```
function block_ip(){
$mysqli_2 = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    if ($mysqli_2->connect_error) {
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Unable to connect to MySQL");
    exit();
    }
   $stmt_block_ip= $mysqli_2->prepare("SELECT b_ip FROM block_ip");   
   $stmt_block_ip->execute();
   $stmt_block_ip->store_result();
   $stmt_block_ip->bind_result($block_iip);
   while( $stmt_block_ip->fetch()){
  if(strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$block_iip) === 0)
    {
       header("Location: ../block.php");
        exit();
    } 
   }
  $stmt_block_ip->close();
 }
```

- Next admin plan is, if the total number of block IP goes > 50, then clear the table by copying all blocked IP & asking the server service provider to add it into the .htaccess to redirect them.

> Is this idea is good? or should I keep it on blocked IP table, but
>   that might slow the page loading, isn't it? as for a long list of blocked
>   IP's? Any better idea?

**Concern II: Algorithm**

On forgot-username.php & forgot-password.php page we have google recaptcha. So we didn't add any flood control algo here, simply for non-user attempted we just redirect them to register page.

> For the security concern is this approach is okay?

Comment: Don't forget you should also rate limit per user account (regardless of IP address).

Comment: This question is better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm fairly certain this'll get closed as *mostly opinion based* ...

Comment: Yes, for registered user attempt I have brute force code ready, which block user login after 5 failure in last 2 hours.

Comment: @CD001 or too broad.

Comment: Then can moderator transfer this question to codereview?

Comment: @mimi I've flagged it for moderator intervention, hopefully that'll get it done.

Comment: Hope I will not get negative reputation for it :(

Comment: You prepare a statement that has no variables. Either use `->query` or change your sql to `"SELECT b_ip FROM block_ip WHERE b_ip = ?"` I don't see why you need to loop thru every result when you can just ask your database if `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is in it.

Comment: That's really a good point, thank you I missed it, it will make it faster.

Comment: @mimi the flag request was declined for the move to CodeReview.

Comment: Then I guess I am at the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My 1st concern got solved as it seems with the WillParky Suggestion: the code below IP block checking should be done faster. I guess I don't need to use .htaccess & transfer blocked IP here and there.

```
  function block_ip(){
  $viewer_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   $mysqli_2 = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    if ($mysqli_2->connect_error) {
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Unable to connect to MySQL");
    exit();
    }
  $stmt_block_ip= $mysqli_2->prepare("SELECT b_ip FROM block_ip WHERE b_ip = 
   ?"); 
  $stmt_block_ip->bind_param('s',$viewer_ip);
  $stmt_block_ip->execute();
  $stmt_block_ip->store_result();

 if($stmt_block_ip->num_rows == 1){
    {
     header("Location: ../block.php");
     exit();
   } 
 }
 $stmt_block_ip->close();
  }
```